# Python 2.7.3 urllib2 Error

Tags: python

When I try to run my python script this error happens. How can I solve this problem ?

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'urllib2']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m.py", line 3, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.9.1-py2.7.egg/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.9.1-py2.7.egg/requests/utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.9.1-py2.7.egg/requests/compat.py", line 38, in <module>
    from urllib2 import parse_http_list
ImportError: cannot import name parse_http_list
```

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986626/python-requests-importerror-cannot-import-name-headerparsingerror) help at all?

Answer (score 2):

you need to upgrade [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/)

```
pip install --upgrade requests
```